# redefine \nomencl_command in LyX

Tags: lyx, glossaries

I am trying to redefine the `\nomencl_command` in LyX, in order to be able to use the `glossaries` package in stead of the obsolete `nomencl`.

LyX allows you to specify the `Nomenclature command`, which by default is set to:

```
makeindex -s nomencl.ist
```

For glossaries the command is thus changed to:

```
makeglossaries
```

However, the LyX implementation of nomencl uses the more recent `.nlo` as an input file, and the `.nls` as an output file. Whereas glossaries uses the 'older' `.glo` and `.gls` Unfortunately, the extensions cannot be specified.

I found that the preferences file only says:

```
\nomencl_command "makeglossaries"
```

but the log output says:

```
makeglossaries "[filename].nlo" -o [filename].nls
```

So my question is where is `\nomencl_command` defined further?

Comment: you might want to try posting on tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: I am familiar with tex.stackexchange.com, but since it concerns redefining a LyX program command, rather than a tex command, I figured stackoverflow would be more suited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant code is in `src/LaTeX.cpp`.
Note below that some diagnostic information is written to the latex debug flag. You can see this info on the terminal if you run LyX with `lyx -dbg latex`.

The following are excerpts from the file `src/LaTeX.cpp` from the soon-to-be-released (a matter of days) LyX 2.1.

```
FileName const nlofile(changeExtension(file.absFileName(), ".nlo"));
// If all nomencl entries are removed, nomencl writes an empty nlo file.
// DepTable::hasChanged() returns false in this case, since it does not
// distinguish empty files from non-existing files. This is why we need
// the extra checks here (to trigger a rerun). Cf. discussions in #8905.
// FIXME: Sort out the real problem in DepTable.
if (head.haschanged(nlofile) || (nlofile.exists() && nlofile.isFileEmpty()))
    rerun |= runMakeIndexNomencl(file, ".nlo", ".nls");
FileName const glofile(changeExtension(file.absFileName(), ".glo"));
if (head.haschanged(glofile))
    rerun |= runMakeIndexNomencl(file, ".glo", ".gls");
```

and

```
bool LaTeX::runMakeIndexNomencl(FileName const & file,
        string const & nlo, string const & nls)
{
    LYXERR(Debug::LATEX, "Running MakeIndex for nomencl.");
    message(_("Running MakeIndex for nomencl."));
    string tmp = lyxrc.nomencl_command + ' ';
    // onlyFileName() is needed for cygwin
    tmp += quoteName(onlyFileName(changeExtension(file.absFileName(), nlo)));
    tmp += " -o "
        + onlyFileName(changeExtension(file.toFilesystemEncoding(), nls));
    Systemcall one;
    one.startscript(Systemcall::Wait, tmp, path);
    return true;
}
```

and

```
// nomencl file
FileName const nls(changeExtension(file.absFileName(), ".nls"));
nls.removeFile();

// nomencl file (old version of the package)
FileName const gls(changeExtension(file.absFileName(), ".gls"));
gls.removeFile();
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm running the 2.1 version, so this is perfect. Any idea how redefining should be done?

Comment: @bquast I don't. Hopefully someone responds to your email on `lyx-devel`.